# CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:864 (execute_process)

Tags: windows, cmake, dlib

I'm trying to build the dlib to enable the GPU use but I'm having difficulties

I'm using:

- cuda toolkit version 12.3.0
- cmake version 3.27.7
- visual studio 2022 version 17.7.5

I also downloaded:

- windows SDK 8.1
- MSVC v140 2015

command to build:

```
cmake . -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -T host=x64 -DDLIB_USE_CUDA=1 -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1
```

terminal output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24247.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24247.2
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using CMake version: 3.27.7
-- Compiling dlib version: 19.24.99
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of void*
-- Check size of void* - done
-- Enabling AVX instructions
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
CMake Warning (dev) at dlib/CMakeLists.txt:630 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0146 is not set: The FindCUDA module is removed.  Run "cmake
  --help-policy CMP0146" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
  set the policy and suppress this warning.

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:864 (execute_process):
  execute_process attempted to output into a file: into a source directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  dlib/CMakeLists.txt:630 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled all the programs and their dependencies, cloned the dlib project again, tried changing the cmake version to 3.9, 3.10, 3.15 and 3.20

Comment: This out of source recommendation is in the CMake documentation here: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Getting%20Started.html#:~:text=CMake%20will%20not%20write%20any,should%20be%20avoided%20if%20possible.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Getting%20Started.html#:~:text=CMake%20will%20not%20write%20any,should%20be%20avoided%20if%20possible.)

Comment: CMake prefers that you don't put the build tree in the same folder as the source code. Instead you can create a build folder in the source code, change directory to the build folder and execute the command with `cmake ..  rest of arguments instead` of `cmake . rest of arguments`